# Unusual file structure with virtualenv in pycharm?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pycharm

[image]

I have created a pycharm virualenv using the SETTINGS->PROJECT INTERPRETER. I then associated it with a project following http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html . Its a django project and the file structure screenshot is above. Does this look correct? I'm confused because normally you create a virtualenv and then start a project inside like:

```
 $ cd developer
 $ mkdir testproject
 $ cd testproject
 $ virtualenv testvenv --no-site-packages
 New python executable in testvenv/bin/python
 Installing setuptools............done.
 Installing pip...............done.
 $ source testvenv/bin/activate
 (testvenv)username:testproject leopard$ 
 $ pip install django
 Downloading/unpacking django
   Downloading Django-1.3.1.tar.gz (6.5Mb):  53%  3.5Mb
 ...
 $ django-admin.py startproject mysite
 $ cd mysite
```

The structure is different here. Why is that?

Comment: What Django version is this? Django changed its default project structure a while ago.

Comment: Simeon, In the file structure shown up top in the screenshot I am using django 1.54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is fine. I always have all my virtualenvs in a directory all together (`~/.virtualenvs`). As long as that is on your path (which it will be because virtualenv puts it there) then it will all work as expected.

A nice thing about having your virtual environment somewhere different is that you don't have to always see and all the packages installed into it when managing your code.

This doesn't have anything to do with the django layout (although that may have changed as well, I don't use Django so I don't know.)

Ps. I actually use [virtualenv wrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which you should definitely check out. It makes it very easy to create/delete/activate virtualenvs. By default this will put all your virtualenvs together in a pre-specified directory.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, Inti.